# How to translate this MSSQL query using "EXCEPT" to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

The problem is with "EXCEPT" which is not supported by MySQL. The goal is to find all rows where all columns (except id) are not identical.

```
SELECT B.*, 'modified'  AS 'changetype'
FROM (
        SELECT * FROM table1 
        EXCEPT
        SELECT * FROM table2 
) S1
INNER JOIN table2  B ON S1.id = B.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky.  You're going to have to list out all the columns in MySQL.    This is probably the closest to what you want:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 t1
                  where t1.id = t2.id and
                        t1.col1 = t2.col1 and
                        t1.col2 = t2.col2 and
                        . . .
                 );
```

Comment: Am I correct that this is also catching records that exist in one table but not the other?

Comment: @Fo.  . . . Just like the query in your question, this only returns ids from `table2`.